# Multiple OR operation in parallel in Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

```
def notNullCheck(df:DataFrame,columns:Column*) {
    df.filter(df(columns(0).isNotNull) || df(columns(1).isNotNull))
}
```

How to generalize the above method if I have 20 columns , I want to avoid writing 20 times the same condition.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming columns is of type `List[Column]`

```
val columns = List(col("a"), col("b"))
```

you can do

```
val conditions = columns.foldLeft(lit(true))((z,c) => z.isNotNull || c.isNotNull)
```

Behind it will be something like this:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.Column = ((((true IS NOT NULL) OR (a IS NOT NULL)) IS NOT NULL) OR (b IS NOT NULL))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `na.drop`:

```
def notNullCheck(df: DataFrame, columns: Column*) {
  df.na.drop(how="all", cols=columns)
}
```

which would translate to the same thing without all `ORs`